# Не могу передать значение в json

Tags: python, json, парсер

Никак не могу решить проблему(Python). Необходимо спарсить данные с сайта, но ввиду того что некоторые значения имеют одинаковый class приходится прибегать к команде find_all и просто указывать их позицию [1], [2] и тд. Необходимые данные собираются, но я никак не могу передать их через json. Выдается ошибка: TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Tag. Как я полагаю, это может быть связанно с тем, что поиск элемента происходит путе find_all, а find_all нельзя задать тип.

```
info_21 = time_info.find_all(class_="section__info")[1]  
info_22 = time_info.find_all(class_="section__info")[2]  

karta = {
    info_21: "Время",
    info_21: "Время1"
}

with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    json.dump(karta, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=1)
```

Comment: Можно попробывать так, str(info_21)

Comment: Так вы посмотрите, что у вас в `info_21` получается. Там видимо некий объект. Кстати, вы в словаре два раза написали один и тот же ключ.